# Remove first 4 bits from a byte array (shift left)

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bit-shift

I have a byte array of 3 bytes : `byte[] VG = new Byte[3];`

This are the values of the array: 00-28-A0 . I have to remove the first 4 bits, and get this result: 02-8A-00

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Do you understand the algorithm to use? If not, what difficulty are you having working it out? If so, what problem are you having implementing it? (Hint: Each byte needs to change. Work out an expression for the new value of each byte in terms of the old values.)

Comment: Does not appear to be a duplicate, as he wants to shift *bits* not *bytes*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am receiving an array , but the first 4 bits , we don't have to use. So I need to make a shift of the bits , but I don't understand home to make it. I read about masking, but all the information that i found was for masking only one byte, In that case I have to move all the bits of the array 4 places left, to make what I want.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Shift Four Left
VG[0] = (byte)((byte)(VG[1] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[0] << 4));
VG[1] = (byte)((byte)(VG[2] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[1] << 4));
VG[2] = (byte)(VG[2] << 4);

// Shift Four Right
VG[2] = (byte)((byte)(VG[2] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[1] << 4));
VG[1] = (byte)((byte)(VG[1] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[0] << 4));
VG[0] = (byte)(VG[0] >> 4);
```

Comment: Live fiddle showing that it works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/D1hDWm

Comment: Great !! It works perfectly, thanks!! . Sorry I don't understand too much the masking.. how would be if I want to shift it to right?? In the example i provided to obtein : 00-02-8A. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ShaunLuttin i didn't know that site before, thank you for that !

Comment: @Nico812 https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6a71f45d.aspx you need >> and << to shift bits. The semantic is "variable << digits". Maybe you can code it as an exercise. The idea was to describe each byte as a combination of other bytes. Instead of using + you could use | "bitwise or".

Comment: Thanks @TimBoss !! I will read it .. i think i could understand it with time. If is posible could you provide me the example shifting right ??  With this you are helping me too much.

Comment: I tried to make the right shift but I couldnt do it..Could you please, anybody tell me how to do it? Thanks for your help..
I am using the example that TimBoss wrote: 

VG[0] = (byte)((byte)(VG[1] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[0] << 4));
VG[1] = (byte)((byte)(VG[2] >> 4) + (byte)(VG[1] << 4));
VG[2] = (byte)(VG[2] << 4);

Now i need that the shift would be to right instead of left. So, if the example is 00-28-A0, i need to get 00-02-8A